# German word that means ‘one who thinks with their hands’. It was a single word, I can not recall it. Any ideas?

Tags: meaning, single-word-request

A presenter in Zurich said a word in German that meant ‘one who thinks with their hands’. It was a single word I believe, I can not recall it. It may be particular to the Swiss. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure it was "think"? I know the phrase of "talking with the hands" for people with high active gestics while talking... But I have no imagination about people thinking with hands... What does it mean?

Answer (score 2):

The term *»mit den Händen denken«* ("thinking with hands") is not very common. The most websites that deal with it are from Switzerland.

Sources:

- [Title of a creative workshop](https://www.thinking-with-hands.de)
  This seems to be an exception, because the association that offers this workshop is from Bavaria.
- [Article about a Swiss film director](https://www.journal21.ch/artikel/mit-den-haenden-denken)
- [Exhibition of a Swiss designer](https://museum-gestaltung.ch/de/ausstellung/willy-guhl/)

---

There are theories about how some people learn the easiest way, and these theories define different learning types:

- People who belong to the **auditive** learning type learn best when they hear something
- the **visual** learning type needs to see something
- the **communicative** learning type must talk with others to learn
- the **haptic** learning type must touch things

There are also some other types in discussion (the **motor** type must walk, etc.), and all these theories are heavily discussed because some researchers have found evidence, that this all might just be an illusion.

However, the point is: There is a haptic type, and in German this is:

> ein haptischer Typ

This is a person that needs to touch things with their hands to better understand them. So this is what you might call a person who thinks with their hands. If you want to have just one word for it, then it is:

> Haptiker

This is a correct word, but it is rare.